# Center a div inside a fullscreen div

Tags: css, position, width, fullscreen, center

I need to center a div (undefined width) horizontaly and vertically inside a fullscreen div.

I have the code below.

outer div:

```
background: #000 url('header.jpg') no-repeat center center /* fixed */;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
```

inner div:

```
left: 50%;
margin-top: -300px;
margin-left: -300px;
max-width: 600px;
position: absolute; 
top: 50%;
z-index: 2;
```

But it is not clean - especially when I resize the window. And this is somehow not centered vertically.

Could you help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Don-t use `position:absolute` in this case. You don't have to use `z-index` because the child will always stay in front of the parent by default. It wasn't your case because the parent was `relative` and the child `absolute` and `position:relative` was giving a greater stacking order for the parent.

So, if your inner div is 50% width and height of the parent, write `top:25%` and `margin:0 auto`;

If it was 70%: `top:15%; margin:0 auto;`

```css
html, body{
width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.outer{background: #000 url('http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/') no-repeat center center /* fixed */;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 100%; 

}
.inner{
height:50%;
width: 50%;
position: relative; 
top: 25%;
background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easy fix is:

```
<outerdiv><center><innerdiv></div></center></div>
```

but a margin of '0 auto' is the correct way to center the div

```
innerdiv {
margin:0 auto;
}
```

You can then adjust the top and bottom accordingly